# Web Service Endpoints, what's the best practice?

Tags: acumatica

So, I've got a project that adds a few fields, and then I need to be able to access those fields via the REST API. I've created a Web Service Endpoint based on 18.200.001 and this has been deployed (via attaching it to a Customization Project) to about 10 tenants.

Now I'm making a small change, added a couple new fields to the customization and added them to the WSE. It's also getting deployed to a new tenant that doesn't have it at all. I left it the same name/version number, thinking that it would just update. That said, it doesn't look like it did anything at one of the tenant, and it apparently didn't copy over to the new tenant.

Additionally, to complicate matters, it appears that on one tenant, the Default 18.200.001 WSE ends at AccountLocation. Is there some process to restore a WSE if it gets whacked out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For the part where the endpoint has not been redeployed to the other site you might want to use the publish with cleanup option of the customization project.

there is more information here as to why :
 https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/(W(6))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=4ee2a834-c0df-4112-8417-b139d927a3fa

But to resume it since the endpoint is data that is stored in the database, the customization project can detect if that endpoint has already been inserted and skip it if it sees it again.

Using the Publish with Clean up option will force it to republish the endpoint.

For the missing part of the endpoint, you can maybe use the erp installer that you use to create the site and attempt to repair the database by upgrading only the database part to the same version.

Comment: when publishing from the project customizations screen, the dialog box presents this as a checkbox called "Execute all database scripts". As best I can tell, its the same as the "Publish with Clean up" option in the customization editor screen.